# Why 1 of 3 parametres of session is null (Java), but in servlet is not null

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

The username in JSP in `null`, why? in servlet I don't have `null` parameter. `name` and `familiya` are working well, only `username` is `null`.

Servlet:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30);
session.setAttribute(username, uservalue);
session.setAttribute(name, namevalue);
session.setAttribute(familiya, familiyavalue);
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(uservalue);  ==== Is NOT null
```

JSP:

```
<%
    HttpSession ses = request.getSession();
    String name =(String)ses.getAttribute("name");
    String familiya =(String)ses.getAttribute("familiya");
    String username = (String)ses.getAttribute("username");
    //out.println(name); out.println(familiya);
    out.println(username);
 %>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/siteg/index?user=<%=username%>"><%=name %> <%=familiya %> </a>
```

Comment: Unlike servlets, in JSP you don't have to do `HttpSession ses = request.getSession();` since it will already have an object of `HttpSession` named `session`.

Comment: thanks , didnt know about it , fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should use `setAttribute` with constant name like this :

```
session.setAttribute("username", uservalue);
session.setAttribute("name", namevalue);
session.setAttribute("familiya", familiyavalue);
```

Same as you are retrieving them!